# Add specific column in rbind

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

```
test <- data.frame(col1 = c("test", "test2"))

df <- data.frame()
```

and use this to keep data all data into the df dataframe

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(stock = test$col1))
```

how is it possible to add a column in the dataframe which have row as many as the nrow(test)?
example the specific string is google
and as the test dataframe has 2 rows I would like to create 2 addition rows in the df frame. Simple solution is this

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(stock = test$col1, name = c("google", "google"))
```

how can I make it automatically knowing the string which is fix "google" and nrow?

Comment: You should use cbind to add columns, and also read about vector recycling

Comment: Why do you create a dataframe only to add that complete dataframe as  "rows" to an empty dataframe? Why not simply add "name" to the df test?

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve? From where do you get "google" ? Why are you binding empty dataframe? What if `df` is not empty? What would be the output? "google" and "Facebook"?

Comment: Probably you are looking for `rbind(df, transform(test, name = 'google'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bazillion possible answers. Here are some approaches:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(name = "google") # adds a column "name" with the value "google"
```

```r
name <- rep("google", length(test$col1)) # creates a vector the exact length of test$col1 with the repeated value "google"
```